# Create "virtual files" in android. Possible?

Tags: android

I want to add a functionality to my app to treat a user's uploaded images online as if they were files on their phone, so all their existing apps can find their images without needing to download them all. Basically tricking the phone into thinking its local instead of online. Any thoughts and how to go about this?

Comment: Whatever for?  If you don't download the image, the phone apps can do anything useful with them other than mention that they exist.  If that's your goal, create a ContentProvider wrapped around a mysql daabase that has the filenames.

Comment: So that they can be downloaded on demand, but still be listed if not yet downloaded